# Custom option to Search a Sorted list faster than Plain Binary Search

Tags: c#, .net, performance, binary-search, sorteddictionary

> Following is the **use-case**:

- Sorted List of `DateTime` type, with granularity in the millisecond
- Search for nearest `DateTime`, which satisfy the supplied `predicate` delegate
- Performance is an issue, since List has 100K+ records, total time span of 10 hours from minimum to maximum index and lot of frequent calls (50+ / run), impacts performance

> What we currently do, **custom binary search** as follows ?

```
 public static int BinaryLastOrDefault<T>(this IList<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate)
 {
            var lower = 0;
            var upper = list.Count - 1;

            while (lower < upper)
            {
                var mid = lower + ((upper - lower + 1) / 2);
                if (predicate(list[mid]))
                {
                    lower = mid;
                }
                else
                {
                    upper = mid - 1;
                }
            }

            if (lower >= list.Count) return -1;
            return !predicate(list[lower]) ? -1 : lower;
}
```

> Can I use **Dictionary** to make it O(1) ?

- My understanding is No, since the input value may not be there and in that case we need to return the closest value, which if in above code returns -1, then last element in the sorted list is the expected result

> Following is the option I am considering

- Data structure like `Dictionary<int,SortedDictionary<DateTime,int>>`
- Total duration DateTime duration between highest and lowest value is 10 hours ~ 10 * 3600 * 1000 ms = 36 million ms
- Created buckets of 60 sec each, total number of elements ~ `36 million / 60 K = 600`
- For any supplied DateTime value, its now easy to find the Bucket, where limited number of values can be stored as `SortedDictionary`, with key as DateTime value and original index as value, thus if required then data can enumerated to find the closest index

In my understanding this implementation, will make the search much faster than Binary search detailed above, since data searched would be substantially reduced, Any suggestion what more can be done to improve the search time further to further improve it in the algorithmic terms, I can try the Parallel options for various independent calls separately

Comment: I haven't given it too much thought, so I may be wrong here, but consider the use of LinkedList<T> instead of using the SortedDictionary<T>.

Comment: That will take away the advantage of the O(1) search in the given bucket and it would always be O(N), also in case of Sorted Dictionary keys are sorted, so its easy to get the relevant value and stop, sorting in linked list has to be custom

Comment: A binary search on 36 million records only takes at most 26 steps, for 100K it's at most 17 steps, which raises the question of where your actual bottleneck is. Is your predicate particularly expensive to evaluate? Does it fail to take into account the structure of the source data, or fail to cache values? *Is* the bottleneck even in the binary search? For a search on homogeneous data (which time-based data tends to be) you can use interpolation search to reduce the number of searches, but typically it's slower than binary search due to the added complexity.

Comment: @JeroenMostert correct, but most of the times, it goes through all the 25/26 operations, since millisecond granularity data is unavailable and it needs the closest index and this is one small operation run huge number of times, performance profiler shows up  as the hotspot, which needs fixing

Comment: My first instinct would be to see if you can remove these lookups altogether, rather than somehow improve on the binary search itself (which is hard). Depending on the kind of predicate, you might be able to pre-calculate data to eliminate the need for searching altogether, or use the result of a previous search to speed up the next ones, or simplify your search criteria. All this requires specific knowledge of what the criteria *are*, though.

Comment: Why don't you use the native method [`BinarySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch) of `List<T>`? Why do you use a custom predicate function instead of utilizing the native `Comparer<DateTime>.Default.Compare` method? Making 25-30 `DateTime` comparisons should be extremely efficient, because `DateTime`s are just fancy `long`s. My guess is that something non-trivial is happening inside the predicate function.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias as mentioned in the question, the element may not exist in the sorted List, then we need to return the closest higher / lower value (based on requirement), which is not handled by the standard Binary search. Also Predicate is supplied at run-time, it doesn't contain DateTime comparison. Predicates are simple logic and performance is impacted due to number of calls, same code is executed over multiple times, so any optimization to the core method, where O(logN) can be translated to O(1) is the solution

Comment: The `BinarySearch` is actually capable of finding the nearest value. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch): *Returns the zero-based index of item in the sorted `List<T>`, if item is found; otherwise, a negative number that is the bitwise complement of the index of the next element that is larger than item.* Regarding your comment about the predicate not comparing dates, I am now confused. How do you perform a binary search for the nearest date without comparing dates?

Answer (score 2):

I made some performance tests using the native [`BinarySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch) method of `List<T>`. The logic for finding the nearest `DateTime` is shown below:

```
public static DateTime GetNearest(List<DateTime> source, DateTime date)
{
    var index = source.BinarySearch(date);
    if (index >= 0) return source[index];
    index = ~index;
    if (index == 0) return source[0];
    if (index == source.Count) return source[source.Count - 1];
    var d1 = source[index - 1];
    var d2 = source[index];
    return (date - d1 < d2 - date) ? d1 : d2;
}
```

I created a random list of 1,000,000 sorted dates, covering a time span of 10 hours from min to max. Then I created an equally sized list with unsorted random dates to search, covering a slightly larger time span. Then changed the build to Release and started the test. The result demonstrated that it is possible to make more than 800,000 searches in less than a second, using only a single core of a relatively slow machine.

Then I increased the complexity of the test by searching in a `List<(DateTime, object)>` containing 1,000,000 elements, so that each comparison needs two extra calls to a `dateSelector` function, which returns the `DateTime` property of each `ValueTuple`.
The result: 350,000 searches per thread per second.

I increased the complexity even further by using reference types as elements, populating a `List<Tuple<DateTime, object>>` with 1,000,000 tuples. The performance was still pretty decent: 270,000 searches per thread per second.

My conclusion is that the `BinarySearch` method is lightning fast, and it would be surprising if it was found to be the bottleneck of an application.